# How to popToRoot on Modal from Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

My question is pretty simple. I noticed using `popToRoot()` in a modal has no effect. `pop()` works fine, while `popAll()` simply behaves like `pop()`.

I don't understand why this happens, and would also like to know the logic behind disabling navigation to the root from modals (or how to navigate to root from a modal, if it's possible).

```
export class SomeModal {
    ...
    // The following has no effect, but works if we push to current 
    // page (rather than  create it as a modal)
    this.navCtrl.popToRoot()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dismiss the modal with a variable and pop to root when it returns to your page something like this in your modal:

```
constructor(private viewCtrl: ViewController){}

public abort() {
  this.viewCtrl.dismiss({popToRoot: true})
```

and in your page or whatever:

```
   modal.onDidDismiss(popToRoot=> {
     if(popToRoot){
     this.navCtrl.popToRoot()
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use .setRoot():

```
this.navCtrl.setRoot(*page module*);
```

If i remember, .pop() will just dismiss the first page on stack, and popAll() will send you to the previus .setRoot();